# Internet Explorer caching data returned from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, caching, jquery, internet-explorer-9

So I'm running into this weird issue. When I'm developing locally, and I run my application in both Firefox and IE, everything works fine.

When I run this application in our integration environment, Firefox doesn't see this issue, but IE does. Basically what's happening is, we give our users the option to store a new row in a database table through an **AJAX** call. The **AJAX** call is made through **JQuery**, absorbed by our controller in C#, and then some info is sent to a proc and stored in the DB table. Once this happens, we can all verify this data has definitely been stored.

There is also functionality to view a table in the application that basically mimics the table where we just stored our data, also accessed via a proc (`select` instead of `insert`/`update`). Now, when this is viewed right after we insert the new row, Firefox shows the new row on the web table, but IE does not - even though both work locally, only Firefox works in integration - so weird.

Now, if the user inserts the new row and then clears his IE cache, he can see the new row come up when he clicks the link.

So my questions are:

> 1) Should I focus on a way possibly in JQuery, to clear the browsers cache everytime the user clicks the link to view stored rows?
>
> 2) Why would this be working in IE locally but not on the integration server?
>
> 3) Is there anything server side I can do within .NET, like possibly a property I can set on the controller methods that both set/view these rows that set IE to ignore cache or something?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `cache` property of the ajax call to false as documented here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'll put this in as well just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the POST verb on those requests that are cached. IE caches GETs but POSTs are OK.
To achieve this add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to your actions.

Comment: this seems to return this error when I try and access those actions now - The resource cannot be found.

Comment: If it helps, they return `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`.